# DoctrineORM using EntityManager->merge()

Tags: doctrine-orm

The description of *merge()* method at doctrine documentations says:

> Merges the state of a detached entity into the persistence context of this EntityManager and returns the managed copy of the entity. The entity passed to merge will not become associated/managed with this EntityManager.

But I saw next code many times:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository(...)->findOne($id);
if (null === $entity) {
    $entity = new Entity();
    $em->persist($entity);
} else {
    $entity->setGeneratedAt(new \DateTime());
    $em->merge($entity);
}

$em->flush();
```

Why *$em->merge($entity)* is used? There is not work with returned copy of the *$entity* and the *$entity* is already **managed** without *merge()* call.

Comment: Where did you see code like this?  In what you showed, I can see no need for the merge.  It could be the author simply does not understand how entities are managed and felt there had to be something to trigger an update.

Comment: Upon further reflection, it is also possible that the author is using a [Deferred Explicit Change Tracking Policy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#deferred-explicit) in which case a persist is needed.  But even in this case, it would be persist and not merge though I think the results would be the same.

Comment: I got project for support at my work and there have such code. It seems wrong for me and I tried to find any examples. And I found this:
https://hotexamples.com/en/examples/doctrine.orm/EntityManager/merge/php-entitymanager-merge-method-examples.html

Comment: Using a merge when pulling an object from the session (or maybe a cache) makes some sense I suppose though it seems a bit fragile.